# unfamiliar with array function term in php

Tags: php, arrays

```
if (!is_array($directories)) {
    $directories = (array)$directories;
}
```

Could someone point me in the right direction as to what (array) part of the code means?

I understand from the if statement that its checking `$directories !is_array` so if true 
      `$directories = (array)$directiories;`

is making `$directories` an array but I can't find anything that relates to (array) online. This piece of code is from a Magento site.

Comment: see the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: You must do basic research before you post.

Comment: In some programming languages, enclosing a `type` within parentheses preceding some expression will cast the expression to the `type`. For example, `(string)21` will cast the `int` value `21` to a `string` value `"21"`. Please look into the subject of "type casting" for more information.

Comment: That's the pointer I need, never heard of the term before and was just typing (array) into google and stack exchange search and not getting the info back. I'll read up on type casting. thanks B. Fleming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are first checking if the $directories variable is an array, if not the (array) directive converts the value (a scalar value) in to an array. So the code is basically returning array($directories). For example:

```
$directories = 'abc';

if (!is_array($directories)) {
    $directories = (array)$directories;
}

var_dump($directories)

/*
This prints 
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "abc"  
}
*/
```

For more details refer: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php